# How to set a custom default "Override URL" in KeePass?

Tags: url, keepass

In KeePass, every entry can have its own `Override URL` field (which one can find in `Edit Entry` > `Properties`). For example if I set it to `cmd://{GOOGLECHROME} "{URL}"` then entry's URL will be opened in Chrome. This setting is useful if one uses more than one browser, for example.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to set a default value to this field, i.e. that unless instructed otherwise, KeePass should use my custom string.

[This](https://keepass.info/help/base/autourl.html) looked promising:

> Globally changing the URL behavior:
> If you want to change the default URL action (i.e. for all URLs), you can add a `KeeUrlOverride` line to the `KeePass.ini` file.

But adding `KeeUrlOverride=cmd://{GOOGLECHROME} "{URL}"` to my `KeePass.ini` doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Template feature.

1. create a group "Templates"
2. create sub-entries (and adjust them as you need)
3. edit db settings (Files > Database settings > Advanced tab) and select the group from the dropdown in the Templates section.

[image]

Now you can click the arrow next the the "new entry" icon and select the template you want
[image]

nb: see also the group settings (right click a group from the tree structure):

[image]